# How to get position from GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLICK?

Tags: typescript, google-maps, ionic4

I create an application and I using google maps native, and I want to get position from on click method:

```
map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLICK).subscribe(e => {

});
```

How can I get lat and lng from this function?
please help me, Thanks.

My onClick method:

```
    map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLICK).subscribe(e => {

    // var latit = '' + e;

    // const latnum = latit.substring(latit.indexOf(' ') + 1, latit.indexOf(','));

    // const lngnum = latit.substring(latit.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1, latit.length - 1);

    console.log(e.latLng.lat());

    const coordinates: LatLng = new LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());

    const position = {
        target: coordinates,
        zoom: 16
    };

    const markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
        position: coordinates,
        title: 'موقعیت شما'
    };

    const marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions)
        .then((marker: Marker) => {
          marker.showInfoWindow();
      });
    map.animateCamera(position);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your event is the e object  then  should be in `e.latLng`

```
    my_lat =  e.latLng.lat();
    my_lng =  e.latLng.lng();  

    alert("Lat ' + my_lat );
    alert("Lat ' + my_lng );
```

Comment: I used of your code but my app was get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next`